# How to get log file using SLF4j in android

Tags: java, android, logging, slf4j, logback

I've implemented code for creating log file using slf4j in android but couldn't succeeded.

First I've added gradle dependency as per below:-

```
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.6.1-RC1'
compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.0.7-1'
```

Then as per the guidelines i created a configuration file in assets folder named as `logback.xml` as per below :-

```
<configuration>
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/sdcard/testFile.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Finally I add a log in my application like below:-

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeActivity.class);
logger.debug("Testing slf4j", "Hello world");
```

Now I ran this program and expecting the a log file there in SDcard but unfortunately no such file is seen. Please let me know if I am missing anything.
If anybody have made it in android application, please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: which android version are you using? does your app has write permission in manifest? I am not shure if newer android versions are allowed to write into the root dir of sdcard? note: not every android app has a folder /sdcard/

Comment: Yes, app has write on external device permission in manifest.

Answer (score 7):

`logback-android` requires `slf4j-api`. `slf4j-android` should not be used, as that's a standalone library that only redirects logs to logcat and does not process `logback.xml`.

From `logback-android`'s [GitHub page](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android), the correct dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
  implementation 'com.github.tony19:logback-android:2.0.0'
}
```