# Setting up SLF4J to log to a file

Tags: android, slf4j

I want to setup SLF4j to log to a file. I found this [Log4j Implementation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826025/log4j-implementation-in-android) on here but sadly I am using a project template within Android Studio.

I would like to know where do I put the xml configuration file?

Comment: When dealing with Android be suspicious if you can't find a Android specific version of a library due to Android not being completely compatible with Java SE. See: [How to get log file using SLF4j in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35883132/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang I dont have an assets folder. I am usiong android studio

Comment: See: [Where to place the 'assets' folder in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18302603/295004)